# Magento 2.4: How can we remove datepicker.js in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, magento2.4, datepicker

How do I remove datepicker.js?? I have tried in layout "default_head_blocks.xml"

````
```<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- 2.4.0 -->
    <head>
        <script src="css/swiper.min.css" /> (this works, that css is available sitewide and is placed in /app/design/frontend/vendor/vendor/web/css

        <remove src="Magento_Ui::js/datepicker.js"/> (Tried this)
        <remove src="js/datepicker.js"/> (tried this)
        <remove src="datepicker.js"/> (also tried this)
        <remove src="calendar.css"/> (yea this aint working either)
    </head>
</page>
````

None of the above works.. is there any way to remove those magento javascripts? They are slowing down the site and they are absolutelly optional to me, Id like to remove many more unused javascripts, but I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

This is because that file is not added via XML, it is a dependency of other scripts.

I can see it is a dependency in at least one file - `lib/web/mage/calendar.js` so you could try removing that too although calendar.js is also required in several other files so I'm not sure that will be an easy task.

The way Magento is built where everything has a dependency on everything else can make trivial tasks like this rather painful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is very clear i just add link reference for you
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove
Take a times for look at this beautiful doc

Answer (score 0):

extend your theme and in your theme : app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml  within

some js files are called via the RequireJS approach:  require/define sections, these cannot be removed using layout approach